# TimeSpan formating in Windows Phone

Tags: format, windows-phone, timespan

I have a `TimeSpan` variable which has the current hour.

```
TimeSpan  time = new TimeSpan(DateTime.Now.Hour, 0, 0);
```

I'm trying to format to the current device Time format. For that I take current format like this and then try to format the time variable

```
string modified = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.LongTimePattern.ToString();
str = time.ToString(modified);
```

And this throws error: `Modified contains {hh:mm:ss tt}`

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its very simple, Just use this line of code.

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now.Date;
DateTime dtfinal = dt.Date + time;
string modified = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.LongTimePattern.ToString();
string check = dtfinal.ToString(modified);
DisplayTimeTB.Text = check;
```